# window.print div element showing whole page on android chrome (prints div section on win 10 chrome)

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to print the text inside the div on android chrome
This works on windows 10 chrome
but on android chrome, it prints, but shows the whole page
with header and print button.

Any help appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv(divName){
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        docunt.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<h2> Test print </h2>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<body>
  <div id="PrintMe" >
        <p>
            I'm trying to print the text inside the div on android chrome<br>
            This works on windows 10 chrome <br>
            but on android chrome, it prints, but shows the whole page<br>
            with header and print button.
        </p>
     </div> 
        <button  id="print" onclick= "printDiv('PrintMe')" > Print </button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code, could that be the culprit? `docunt.body.innerHTML` should be `document.body.innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks for that but I corrected and just the same.